# Label of UIButton appears intermittently inside a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView with some data. One of controls is a UIButton, with a label assigned. So, in rare cases, when I push the UITableView screen, the buttons appears without label. After I scroll the UITableView or rotate the device, the label appears.

I put a NSLog entry inside the drawRect method. And It's not called in some cases.

Some advices?

Thanks

Comment: You'll find that posting some code will get you much further around here. It is difficult for anyone to help you when we can't see some code.

Comment: I'm according you. Really, without pieces of code it's hard to understand. I sent this post without the source code on hope to find someone with same problems.

My source code is too big to send entire to here. I'll try isolate the part of problems to test, and give feedback here. Thanks.

Comment: we not want your whole code you just paste you button add on cell and label add on button code paste it here without code we cant help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing my code I saw some characteristic that caused the problem. The process of construction of my screen was occurring in a different thread of the events thread. So, I fixed this and everything is fine now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i found same problems that some methods rarely not called. make sure delegate is properly set and then check the result